# Get the intersection of two dataframes of coordinates R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with geocodes. The first looks something like this:

```
spoints<- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6),y=c(6,5,4,3,2,1))
```

spoints maps a country.

My second data frame looks like this:

```
polyData<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),y=c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1),
col=c("a","b","c",etc.), id=c("a","b","c",etc.), average=c(44,33,66,55,etc))
```

This one contains coordinates to create voronoi clusters/polygons. but these are sketching polygons overlapping into the ocean.
So, I want to avoid that and have them stop at the country boundaries.

But now, I am having difficulty using GPC library or the others.

How can I do this?

Comment: Which library are you working with - [GPC in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/GPC/versions/0.1/topics/GPC-package) doesn't seem to be spatial?